# Pregunta Sobre Tablas sin relacionar en una BD

Tags: base-de-datos

Mi pregunta es si es posible en un modelo de datos en MySQL pueden haber tablas sin relacionar, muchas gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 0):

Si, es posible, a veces se necesita alguna tabla auxiliar para mantener un estado o algo asi.